# Ignore White Spaces in GitExtensions Pending Changes

Tags: git-extensions

In GitExtensions pending changes window in Visual Studio how do i get it to ignore white spaces. when i use the format document it often tabs in old code but those line haven't really changes. the problem is it looks like the whole class has changed and makes it easy to miss actual changes.

I have tried to configure kdiff and also tried setting the diff tool in gitextensions to use winmerge. none of them have an effect.

**Mergetool**
C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/winmergeu.exe

**MergeTool Command**
"C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/winmergeu.exe" -e -u -dl "Original" -dr "Modified" "$MERGED" "$REMOTE"

**DiffTool**
C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/winmergeu.exe

**DiffTool command**
"C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/winmergeu.exe" -e -u "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"

Answer (score 5):

In the difference window you can choose 'ignore whitespaces' in the context menu. Hope this helps!

Comment: The window i am talking about is the Git Pending Changes. Right click a file > Git Pending Changes